# Hosting React project on Github pages while developing

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Is there a way to host the master branch of my React project on Github pages, while continuing to work in some other branch (say, development)?

P.S: I am a newbie to hosting React on Github. I will be very thankful if you could provide an in-depth explanation, or guide me to some resource that is detailed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites), only the `gh-pages` branch of your repo will be published, and it can be an entirely separate branch from your other development.

At a quick glance, https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f looks like a good tutorial for deploying React apps with Create React App. The Create React App docs also have a section on deployment. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment